# Do the support libraries provide all the introduced apis and methods?

Tags: android

I think the title says it all. I'm simply wondering whether the support libraries are selective or if they provide all the newly introduced `APIs` and `methods`.

In particular, I'm looking at the `TelephonyManager.onUssdResponse` class methods updated in `v.26`.

I can't seem to find any indication of whether or not it is implemented in the support libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm simply wondering whether the support libraries are selective or if they provide all the newly introduced APIs and methods.

They are very, very selective. I would estimate that <10% of new Android features can be reproduced in a library at all, and only a subset of those actually get implemented in one of the official support libraries. Most new Android features — such as new callbacks from a system service — cannot be backported via a library.